How to use ruff as fixer in vim with ALE
I'm using ale in vim, and I want to add ruff as fixer for python.
So, in .vimrc, I added:
let g:ale_fixers = {                                                           
\   'python': ['ruff'],                                                    
\   'javascript': ['eslint'],                                              
\   'typescript': ['eslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck'],                     
\}       

Then, when executing in vim the command ALEFix, I've go this error:

117: Unknown function: ale#fixers#ruff#Fix

Do you know how to integrate ruff as fixer in vim with ALE ?

Maybe something is wrong with your ale install? That function is defined in autoload/ale/fixers/ruff.vim. You shouldn't need to do anything unusual.

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/editors/setup/#vim , open "With the ALE plugin for Vim or Neovim." The docs shows
" Linter
let g:ale_linters = { "python": ["ruff"] }
" Formatter
let g:ale_fixers = { "python": ["ruff_format"] }


There is both a ruff fixer (which calls ruff --fix) and a ruff_format fixer (which calls ruff format) in the ale distribution (as well as the ruff linter), so suggesting to use a different fixer doesn't answer the question of how to use the ruff fixer.
